# How to add a clear button to the keyboard on tvos?

Tags: keyboard, uitextfield, tvos

I have been looking for a way to add a clear button on tvos. I tried adding a button to self.rightView of the UITextField.

But it does not work. Is there another solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this doesn't answer your exact question about how to add a button to a text field, but as a user you can clear any text field by clicking and holding the backspace button.